# Desktop Application for youtube(Login and update profile from a desktop appliaction)

Tags: c#, api, youtube

Greetings,
Can someone help me with this? I am trying to make a desktop application for Youtube where user can Login and update his profile etc. I am doing following

```
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using Google.GData.YouTube;
using Google.GData.Extensions.MediaRss;
using Google.YouTube;

//Send Connection Request //I am doing something wrong here

YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("example app", developerKey, username, password);

YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
```

I don't know what to do next and

how can I ensure if username and password are right? Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing the same, and what you did is correct. You just need to catch the Exception that occurs. My code:

```
        Video newVideo = new Video();
        newVideo.Title = textBoxTitle.Text;// "Smideo Generated Movie";
        newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Travel", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
        newVideo.Keywords = textBoxKeyWords.Text;
        newVideo.Description = textBoxDescription.Text;
        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
        newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Test, Example",
          YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));
        try
        {
             createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);
        }
        catch(InvalidCredentialsException c)
        {
             doSomethingAboutInvalidCredentials(c);
        }
```